# how to modify and publish camera_info?

Tags: ros, image, camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.

I would like to make a cropped image from raw image in python.

In my program,
I can subscribe `/usb_cam/image_raw` (`sensor_msgs/Image`, height=480, width=640) and `/usb_cam/camera_info` (`sensor_msgs/CameraInfo`).

Then, I modified roi in `/usb_cam/camera_info` like below,

```
edited_camera_info.roi.x_offset = 320
edited_camera_info.roi.y_offset = 240
```

and publish edited camera info and image.

```
pub_edited_image.publish(no_edited_image)
pub_edited_camera_info.publish(edited_camera_info)
```

However, there are no differences between `/usb_cam/image_raw` and `/editted_image_raw`.

Is it possible to crop a part of an image by modifying camera_info?
Or, is there any alternative ways to realize to crop an image?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/244971/how-to-modify-and-publish-camera_info?/) by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on ROS Answers with karma: 39 on 2016-10-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No, I don't think that is supposed to work like that.

For cropping an image have a look at the [image_proc](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc) package, in particular the [image_proc/crop_decimate](http://wiki.ros.org/image_proc#image_proc.2BAC8-electric.image_proc.2BAC8-crop_decimate) nodelet.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [baozhang](https://answers.ros.org/users/25430/baozhang/) on 2016-10-04**:
Thank you for replying.

I decided to use image_proc/crop_decimate nodelet.